# Changing RBG value doesn't seem to work in C

Tags: c, cs50

I'm supposed to change the RGB color to gray by getting the average of the 3 and then assigning that average to each of the RBG colors(red, blue, green) however it isn't working.

First I'll post my code for the grayscale part:

```
#include "helpers.h"

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
     {
       RGBTRIPLE rgbt = image[i][j];
       BYTE average = (rgbt.rgbtBlue/3)+(rgbt.rgbtGreen/3)+(rgbt.rgbtRed);
       *rgbt.rgbtBlue = *average;
       *rgbt.rgbtGreen = *average;
       *rgbt.rgbtRed = *average;
     }        
   }
   return;
}
```

And since its important, here where the RGBT values are mentionned: (in another file, mentionned in the header for helpers.h, called bmp.h):

```
/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx.
 */
 typedef struct
 {
   BYTE  rgbtBlue;
   BYTE  rgbtGreen;
   BYTE  rgbtRed;
 } __attribute__((__packed__))
 RGBTRIPLE;
```

The error message is as follows :

> indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)

Thanks for your help (and I know know that cs50 isn't the best course but the Harvard diploma helps!).

Comment: `BYTE` is not a pointer AFAIK. You can't dereference it.

Comment: `(rgbt.rgbtRed)` -> `(rgbt.rgbtRed/3)`

Comment: So should I remove the BYTE?

Comment: Why have you added the unary `*` operator everywhere? What do you think it does?

Comment: `*rgbt.rgbtBlue` -> `rgbt.rgbtBlue` (several places)

Comment: `*average` -> `average` (several places)

Comment: Dividing each byte by 3 and then adding them up is likely to cause problems due to the inherent truncation of integer arithmetic. You should really add each component to a 'double' variable, divide *that* by 3.0 and then convert it back to the byte answer.

Comment: Doesn't it mean "go to this address"?

Comment: And I would expect the loop to end with the line `image[i][j] = rgbt;`

Comment: @Ragnaroni But e.g. `average` isn't an "address" (it's not a pointer).

Comment: Also note that `RGBTRIPLE rgbt = image[i][j];` ***copies*** the value from `image[i][j]` into the distinct and separate structure object `rgbt`. Modifying the copy (the values in `rgbt`) will not change the original values (in `image[i][j]`). I suspect you really want something like `RGBTRIPLE *rgbt = &image[i][j];` and then e.g. `rgbt->rgbtBlue = average;` Or why not `image[i][j].rgbBlue = average;`?

Comment: OK I understand that its not an address but don't I want to copy the value from image[i][j] into rgbt and then change it?

Comment: @Ragnaroni you "copy" the values from `image[i][j]` into `rgbt`  when you do: `RGBTRIPLE rgbt = image[i][j];` The `=` is an assignment so that the object on the left gets the value of the object on the rigth

Comment: Oh so should I make it "=="?

Comment: @Ragnaroni no, **not** `==` but just a single `=` and remove all the `*`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
     {
       RGBTRIPLE rgbt = image[i][j];
       BYTE average = (rgbt.rgbtBlue + rgbt.rgbtGreen + rgbt.rgbtRed) / 3;
       rgbt.rgbtBlue = average;
       rgbt.rgbtGreen = average;
       rgbt.rgbtRed =  average;
       image[i][j] = rgbt;   
     }        
   }
   return;
}
```

Hint: you can simplyfy this by getting rid of the `rgbt` variable. You only need one line of code inside the inner for loop.

**Problems in your original code:**

This is wrong:

```
BYTE average = (rgbt.rgbtBlue/3)+(rgbt.rgbtGreen/3)+(rgbt.rgbtRed);
```

because you didn't divide `rgbt.rgbtRed` by 3, and anyway you should first add all values and then divide the whole thing by 3 which this will prevent roundoff errors:

```
BYTE average = (rgbt.rgbtBlue + rgbt.rgbtGreen + rgbt.rgbtRed) / 3;
```

This is wrong, you use `*` to dereference something that is not a pointer:

```
 *rgbt.rgbtBlue = *average;
```

You simply want:

```
 rgbt.rgbtBlue = average;
```

And last but not least you still need to modify the original value in the image by adding this:

```
 image[i][j] = rgbt;
```

Comment: OK It's functionning however it tells me that "Could not open infile.bmp."?
(Im so sorry, I really suck at this :D)

Comment: "Could not open infile.bmp.", most likely means that the file does not exist. Filenames are case are probably case sensitive or your platform or the file  does not exist where you think. That's an entirely new question.

Comment: Yeah, I made a silly mistake and copied the space before the code, thanks!

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question here?
`code`BYTE sepiaRed = .393 * rgbt.rgbtRed + .769 * rgbt.rgbtGreen + .189 * rgbt.rgbtBlue;
`code`
Has an error message ;"259.821 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned char'"

Comment: @Ragnaroni a color value ranges from 0 to 255. You need to make sure your result fits into this range. Hint: apply basic school maths.

Comment: @Ragnaroni Hint 2:  how much is 0.393 +0.769 + 0.189?

Comment: Ok I got an idea : 

wait should i round it and turn them into floats?

Comment: @Ragnaroni probably not the right thing here. Maybe you should ask a new quesion.